# Cannot import an existing AAR

Tags: android-studio, aar

I might have forgotten how to do this but am trying to import an existing AAR and it is not allowing me??? Am I missing something here???? Looked all over and several are mentioning the option to import AAR package which I cannot see??? Running Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your in the wrong section. Your mixing up the import of an `.aar` file with opening an -- quote from your screenshot -- "Gradle or Eclipse project".

Use the "Android Library" section at the left. For details look up the corresponding [Android Dev Docs' section on .aar files](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library).

Comment: BINGO! Thanks for the memory refresh!